# Taylor Series of Rational Function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I must admit that my understanding of Taylor and power series is flimsy at best. I am supposed to find the Taylor series for the following function centred at $x=0$:

$$\frac{1}{(1-5x)^2}$$

I honestly have no idea as to the approach to take from here. Should I look to relate this to the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$, attempt to determine the first few terms of the series and notice a pattern, or something else entirely? I'm not necessarily looking for an answer but rather an explanation as to how to best tackle problems of this nature.

Comment: Hint : Differentiate $\frac{1}{1-5x}$ to get the desired relation

Comment: If one applies generalized binomial expansion on $f(x)=(1-5x)^{-2}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)=\frac{1/5}{1-5x}$ so that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-5x)^2}$.  Now, differentiate the geometric series for $f(x)$ term by term.

Comment: So my first step is to integrate the given function?

Comment: The first step is to find the geometric series representation for $f(x)=\frac{1/5}{1-5x}$.  The second step is to differentiate that series term by term.

Comment: And how might I do that?

Comment: Do you know how to find the geometric series for $\frac{1}{1-5x}$?

Comment: Is it simply $5(n)^x\;\ \;n\in(-1,1)$?

Comment: Ah, I see. So we'd have the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^nx^n$, no?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget the $1/5$.  Then, simply differentiate term by term.

Comment: Are we differentiating with respect to $n$ or $x$?

Comment: Lanier, the index $n$ is a discrete dummy index.  After you sum, do you see its appearance?  If not, then does that help answer the question?

Comment: Yes, accounting for the $1/5$, would it not become $\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(5x)^{n-1}$?

Comment: Not quite.  So, $$\frac{1}{(1-5x)^2}=1+10x+75x^2+500x^3 +\cdots =\sum_{n=1}^\infty (5x)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your extended assistance with this!